# What's changing the owner on my log files?

Tags: 12.10, logging

I have several log files in `/var/log/mythtv` that need to be owned by `mythtv.users`. In versions of Ubuntu prior to 12.10 if I did:

```
sudo chown mythtv.users mylogfile
```

that worked fine and my log files would stay belonging to `mythtv.users`. However, since upgrading to 12.10 Ubuntu keeps changing the ownership of my log files back to `syslog.adm`.

Is there any way to stop Ubuntu changing the ownership of my log files?

Comment: Would it be a solution to add mythtv to the group adm ? That way you wont need the logfiles to be owned by mythtv.

Comment: Thanks I did try that, but whatever is changing the permissions sets the file to be read only for the adm group.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `setgid` of the `/var/log/mythtv` ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/6mb2joass/index.html )